VBA not preserving leading zeros
The goal is to have VBA generate a table based on values it collects from other sheets in the same excel workbook.  The problem is that the leading zeros of the SKU numbers are being truncated the output table.
Sub sku_updater()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("SKU Numbers")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects(1) ' or e.g. "Table1"
    If slo.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data in source table """ & slo.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("SKU Updater")
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(1) ' or e.g. "Table6"
    
    ' Exchange rate
    Dim exch_r As Variant
    
    exch_r = dws.Range("B10").Value
    
    ' Trade Agreement Price
    Dim trade_agreement As Variant
    
    ' Input journal number
    JournalNumber = InputBox("Enter update journal number")
    
    ' Copy values to array
    Dim dataArray() As Variant
    ReDim dataArray(1 To srCount, 1 To 25)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To srCount
        dataArray(i, 1) = JournalNumber
        dataArray(i, 2) = i + 1 ' row numbers
        dataArray(i, 3) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value ' SKU number
        dataArray(i, 8) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 6).Value
        dataArray(i, 9) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 7).Value
        dataArray(i, 10) = 1.01
        dataArray(i, 11) = 100
        dataArray(i, 12) = "price unit"
        ' Check if the value is not 99999999 before multiplying
        If slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 10).Value <> 99999999 Then
            dataArray(i, 13) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 10).Value * exch_r
        Else
            dataArray(i, 13) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 10).Value
        End If

        dataArray(i, 14) = "monetary_unit"
        dataArray(i, 15) = Date
        dataArray(i, 17) = 0
        dataArray(i, 19) = 0
        dataArray(i, 20) = 1
        dataArray(i, 21) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 8).Value
        dataArray(i, 23) = "No"
        dataArray(i, 24) = "Yes"
        dataArray(i, 25) = "Yes"
    Next i
    
    ' Write array to destination table
    With dlo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
        .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(srCount).Value = dataArray
    End With
        
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Table """ & dlo.Name & """ updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

The problem area is dataArray(i, 3) = slo.DataBodyRange.Cells(i, 1).Value ' SKU number.  Table6, the target, is populated with values exactly the way I would want, except for the SKU number column.  I assume excel / VBA is converting the SKUs to the general data type before inserting into Table6, resulting in the leading zeros being truncated.  I have tried .Text instead of .Value, but this did not work.

To preserve data exactly as entered, you need to format the cell as text before assigning it a value.   How are the cells in the SKU column of the source table formatted? As Text, or something else?

@TimWilliams Thanks for responding, the answer suggested by whomever closed my question doesn't solve my issue.  For some reason even if the destination column is Text data type, excel seems to be applying the general type then inputting those values into the text type column.  The source data has leading zeros, and another VBA table I have also preserves zeros.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get any math operators to work on the columns in that other VBA module.

What is the source column number format though?

@TimWilliams The source column is a power query table and excel shows the column as the general data type when I click into the SKU column.

If that's the case it's not clear how the zeroes are maintained in the source table - do the values have a leading apostrophe to force them to "text" ?

Try adding .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(srCount).Columns(3).NumberFormat="@" before adding the values to the destination table.

@TimWilliams That worked perfectly.  I put it right above the .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(srCount).Value = dataArray  line and it worked!  Thank you so very much!

With dlo.HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(srCount):         .Columns(3).NumberFormat = "@":         .Value = arr:     End With

Good to hear it worked out.
